# Executing psql through plink within a bat using quotes within quotes

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, psql, quotes, plink

This simple update executed within a bat is not working.

```
@echo off
plink -pw passcode user@192.168.10.110 "psql -U sa DATABASE -c 'update users set username = 'Last_Name' where iduser = 12345'"
```

The idea is to execute the psql update in a remote linux server from his command line. I know the problem is related on how to set the quotes to the char value *Last_Name* assigned to the char column *username* but i don't know the correct sequence of scape characters.

Comment: your escape sequence are good. Inside " (doublequote), you can use ' (singlequote) as much as you like.

Answer (score 1):

escape your `sql` string with backlash character.

```
@echo off
plink -pw passcode user@192.168.10.110 "psql -U sa DATABASE -c \"update users set username = 'Last_Name' where iduser = 12345\""
```